# get new grid.options.columns

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").options.columns to get the column order and doing some column work. After the columnReorder was trigerred in the grid(after changing the column order from the UI), still I am geeting the old column order from the options.columns. I want to see the new column order. Is there any way to get it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your code to your post? That will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
var columns = grid.options.columns;
 if (columns.length > 0) {//finding the index of the column to modify the required column} replacing the second line of code with the answer given , I am getting the column order which is in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```
$(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid").columns
```